# SQLite return sum of duplicate rows based on array

Tags: select, sqlite, array, sum

If I have a simple table `fruits` that looks like this:

```
+---+---------+------+
|   | name    | lbs  |
+---+---------+------+
| 1 | apple   | 0.25 |
| 2 | melon   | 3.00 |
+---+---------+------+
```

In a query, I need to return the sum of the `lbs` based on an array. For example, I could have the array `('melon', 'melon', 'apple')` to return the value `6.25`.

A query like this won't work:

```sql
SELECT SUM(lbs) FROM fruits WHERE name IN ('melon', 'melon', 'apple');
```

It returns `3.25` because even though `melon` is listed twice, it only counts it a single time.

How can I get the `select` statement to sum duplicate rows as dictated by the given array? I've done a lot of searching of StackExchange, but maybe I'm not using the right keywords to find the answer. Thanks in advance for you help/patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [(virtual) table](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) with the desired names, then join it with the actual table:

```
WITH my_array(name) AS (
  VALUES ('melon'), ('melon'), ('apple')
)
SELECT SUM(lbs)
FROM fruits
JOIN my_array USING (name);
```

Comment: beautiful! Thank you!